# Non-zero terms in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I know that |$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$| converges to $0$ as $|z| \to \infty$, and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges absolutely for every $|z| >1$ ($z$ is complex). Is it true that all the $a_k$ are equal to zero. This seems to be so but I am unable to prove it.

Basically, if there is a lower bound for |$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$| in terms of $|z|$ then this might be used to show that convergence to $0$ fails. However, I have been unsuccessful with this approach. For example, splitting the $a_k$ into
positive and negative parts in the hope of making the absolute value behave better
did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)  implies that what you have is a bounded entire function. [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) then implies that the function is constant, and considering the boundary behaviour 'at infinity' you then see that the function vanishes everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I have missed that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges absolutely only in $|z| > 1$. This is not an entire function then.

Comment: By the [Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), if your series converges absolutely for $z=2$, then it also converges absolutely for $|z|<2$.